# Update Angular model after setting input value with jQuery (trigger input and change do not work)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular

I'm trying to login to this Angular App using jquery.

https://goairlines.nectir.co/app/login

My code is something like

```
var input = jQuery('input[name=emailModel]');
input.val('xxx');
input.trigger('input'); // Use for Chrome/Firefox/Edge
input.trigger('change');

var input = jQuery('input[name=passwordModel]');
input.val('xxx');
input.trigger('input'); // Use for Chrome/Firefox/Edge
input.trigger('change');
```

But it does not update the model and it still believes the fields are empty. When I write that in the console and then click sign it, it does not work. 
Once this works I would trigger a click on that button to submit the form.

((((In case you wonder I'm trying to do this for a xamarin mobile webapp that will store the password of the user the first time he logs in, and then log him in each time he opens the app. I tried storing cookies, saving the state of the session and other things, but none of those worked to keep the user logged in after closing the webview/app... I ended up just trying to go in to the page and input the user name and password with jQuery))))

Comment: it may not work because DOM is not loaded when you try to do that. Try wrap in into .ready() function.

Comment: Not sure if that will work since the Jquery is external. (its called by the browser). But I will try today and let you know @VitaliiChmovzh

Comment: Yep as I thought it doesnt makes any sense because when I call that the page is already loaded/ready. I'm running jquery once the page is ready to do this, externally. 
I'm using a web view to load this page and then trying to login

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just making a POST request directly?  When the submit btn is clicked, a POST is made and json data is sent:

```
// POST https://goairlines.nectir.co/app/api/v1/login
{
  _username: "test",
  _password: "test"
}
```

Try sending the right credentials to the server directly

Comment: Doing that returns the authentication and refresh token, but it does not log me in to the application nor lets me browse it.